# Insert JS Header

Tags: javascript, dom, insert, header

i try to understand why this isn't working.
Could anyone help?

It should insert a header by clicking on the button.

```
<head>
<script>
function header() {
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
var neuesP = document.createElement("p");
var text = document.createTextNode("Ich bin ein Header");
neuesP.appendChild(text);
newDiv.appendChild(neuesP);
document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, document.body.firstElementChild);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Hallo, ich bin ein Test.
<button onclick="header()">TEST</button>
</body>
```

Comment: It's working for me. Is this what you're after? https://jsfiddle.net/urz7mmnd/

Comment: I was just converting your code to a snippet, and discovered it works as well. Did you perhaps fix a typo while posting the question?

Comment: Puhh - seams like - but really thank you <3